# How to set the title of the entry that the browser displays for history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, dom, title, pushstate

I use `history.pushState( stateObject, title, url )` to push new entries to the history stack of the browser. Despite its name the second parameter `title` does not set the title of the entry that is displayed in the browser's history. If I understand correctly `title` is reserved for future use and currently ignored by all browsers. It should be safe to pass `''` here and my findings support this.

Hence, I wonder how to set the label that the user will see in his history and I thought `document.title` would do the job. So my code looks something like this

```
var myTitle = /* code to generate title here */
var myURL = /* code to generate url here */
var myState = /* code to generate realizable state object here */    

document.title = myTitle;
history.pushState( myState, '', myURL ); // 2nd parameter can also be myTitle; this has no effect on all major browsers
```

However, it does not work as expected. More precisely I encounter a strange off-by-one error. It seems that `pushState` does not create a new history entry using the new `document.title` but the previous title. I guess the problem is that the DOM is not updated immediately but only after JS leaves the current call stack. So `document.title = myTitle` becomes effective after `pushState`.

The [note below bullet point 8 at chapter 5.5.2](http://w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history-1) of the HTML5 specification of the W3C says:

> The `title` is purely advisory. User agents might use the title in the user interface.

This is the behaviour as implemented by all major browsers. Howerver the UI and the new title is only updated after the JS function returns.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
  var character = e.state;

      document.title = "Title | ";

});
```

Comment: And how does this help to set the correct title that is used for the entry in the browser's history?

I am referring to the note below bullet point 8 at chapter 5.5.2 of the HTML 5 specifications [[https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history-1]]. It says: "The title is purely advisory. User agents might use the title in the user interface." But the problem is that the UI is not updated until the end of the JS function.

Comment: set that title to a variable before push.pushState() then you can access the title inside the EventListener. You can use so many logic's here.

Comment: I believe you did not get the problem. The problem is that `pushState` creates a new entry in the browser's history and uses the wrong (out-dated, previous) title to create this entry. Hence the user of the web-application who picks an item from the history is mislead to a different page then he expects because the title (inside the browser's history) is off-by-one. This has absolutely nothing to do with the 'popstate'-event. Perhaps, you should re-read the question.